# Tradingview Pine: Activate alert not before a certain price is touched

Tags: conditional-statements, alert, pine-script, price

- is that possible?

Can a script for example use the price of a horizontal line object as a trigger input in its alert condition?

Answer (score 1):

No, scripts cannot access chart drawing, but you can configure an alert on a line drawing using the chart UI.

Comment: Yes, I know, thank you...  I'd be glad if there was a way to activate a certain alert script when a horizontal line is crossed.

Comment: It's an oft-requested feature and would be really handy, but scripts currently have very little visibility on the chart as a whole. Changing this would require revising the current architecture. While improvements to Pine are being deployed at a steady pace, sorry to say that one is currently not envisioned for the near future.

Comment: I see. Thank you